# Get the caret position for Blazor text input

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

I am working on a Blazor textarea input. What I want to achieve is whenever user types "@" character, I am going to popup a small window and they can select something from it. Whatever they select, I will insert that text into the textarea, right after where they typed the "@".

I got this HTML:

```
<textarea rows="10" class="form-control" id="CSTemplate" @bind="original" @oninput="(e => InputHandler(e.Value))" @onkeypress="@(e => KeyWasPressed(e))"></textarea>
```

And the codes are:

```
protected void InputHandler(object value)
{
    original = value.ToString();
}

private void KeyWasPressed(KeyboardEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.Key == "@")
    {
        showVariables = true;
    }
}

protected void AddVariable(string v)
{
    original += v + " ";
    showVariables = false;
}
```

This worked very well. The showVariables boolean is how I control the pop-up window and AddVariable function is how I add the selected text back to the textarea.

However, there is one small problem. If I've already typed certain text and then I go back to any previous position and typed "@", menu will still pop-up no problem, but when user selects the text and the insert is of course only appended to the end of the text. I am having trouble trying to get the exact caret position of when the "@" was so I only append the text right after the "@", not to the end of the input.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did fast demo app, check it https://github.com/Lupusa87/BlazorDisplayMenuAtCaret

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I got it - I was able to use JSInterop to obtain the cursor position $('#CSTemplate').prop("selectionStart") and save the value in a variable. Then use this value later in the AddVariable function.

Comment: Hi @Franky - are you able to share your completed code solution?  I'm trying to do something similar and just can't quite get it right

Answer (score 0):

you can set your condition in `InputHandler` and when you are checking for the @   to see if it's inputed you can also get the length to see that if it's just an @ or it has some characters before or after it obviously when the length is 1 and value is @ it means there is just an @ and if length is more than one then ...

Comment: This wouldn't work as there can be multiple @ in the input. I wouldn't know which one was just entered ...